# How to use a maven 1 repository with maven 2?

Tags: maven-2, maven, repository, maven-3, pom.xml

I am having problem building my project (using maven 2) which references some jars from a maven 1 repository.

The scenario: My company has a private maven 1 repository that has the following info:

```
<url>http://my-company-maven1-repo/maven-repository<url>
```

It has the layout of:

```
   maven-repository
              |_repository
                     |_ ....
                     |_ ....
                     |_vectorgraphics
                              |_jars
                                  |_freehep_swing-2.0.3.jar
                                  |_freehep_io-2.0.2.jar
```

What I have tried:
 1. Following the guide here: [relevant maven official docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-m1-repos-with-m2.html)
    My mvn2 pom.xml:

```
<repository>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>my-repo</id>        <-- I made up a temporary id/name
  <name>my_repo></name>
  <url>http://my-company-maven1-repo/maven-repository<url>
  <layout>
<repository>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>vectorgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>freehep-swing</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
    <scope>jar</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The result was weird, my company's maven1 repo was completely *ignored*. Instead, mvn2 attempted to download the jar from "maven2 central":

```
Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/vectorgraphics/freehep-swing/2.0.3/freehep-swing-2.0.3.pom
```

And the resulted freehep-swing-2.0.3.pom (in my local .m2/repository/) has the following errors:

```
legacy-http\://my-company-maven1-repo/maven-repository/.lastUpdated=1305430120039
http\://my-company-maven1-repo/maven-repository/.error=Could not transfer artifact vectorgraphics\:freehep-swing\:pom\:2.0.3 from/to my-repo (http\://my-company-maven1-repo/maven-repository)\: No connector available to access repository my-repo (http\://my-company-maven1-repo/maven-repository) of type legacy using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
http\://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.error=
http\://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1305430120281
```

If anyone can point out to me how to fetch that freehep_swing-2.0.3.jar from the maven1 repository (with layout shown above), I would really really appreciate that.

Thanks,

Tung

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Nexus repository manager](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) is able to proxy Maven 1 repositories for Maven {2,3} clients.

Maven 3 no longer has the possibility of using 'legacy' repositories, see [Maven 3.x compatibility notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-LegacystyleRepositories).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But is it true that what I wanted to do cannot be achieved by just modifying my mvn2 project's pom.xml ? I thought Nexus was only needed in the 'opposite situation' because "there's just no way to get Maven 1 to recognize a Maven 2 repo" [ http://www.disasterarea.co.uk/blog/?p=196  ] . Considering what that blog and the [http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-m1-repos-with-m2.html] both say, I thought it was just some manipulation of the pom.xml and everything will be okay. Please let me know.

Comment: I believe that you are using Maven 3, which no longer supports the 'legacy' layout. If that is the case, you must use a repository manager. See https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-LegacystyleRepositories for details.

Comment: The constructor for [WagonRepositoryConnector](http://sonatype.github.io/sonatype-aether/xref/org/sonatype/aether/connector/wagon/WagonRepositoryConnector.html) throws an exception if the repository layout [RemoteRepository.getContentType()](http://sonatype.github.io/sonatype-aether/xref/org/sonatype/aether/repository/RemoteRepository.html) is not `"default"`.