# Maven : Failed to collect dependencies

Tags: maven

I have exported a Maven Project . (So i dont have settings.xml file with me )

When i ran the Mavens POM.xml file the build is failin due to this reasson

> Failed to execute goal on project bayer-ws: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.tata:bayer-ws:war:1.0: Failed to collect
>   dependencies for [com.tata:bayer-util:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.tata:bayer-model:jar:1.0 (compile), com.tata:bayer-samples:jar:1.0
>   (compile), com.tata:bayer-mw:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.tata:bayer-fixml:jar:1.0 (compile), cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3
>   (runtime), jdom:jdom:jar:1.1 (compile),
>   org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.5 (runtime),
>   javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided), junit:junit:jar:4.4
>   (test), org.easymock:easymockclassextension:jar:2.3 (test),
>   org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.3 (test),
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-http:jar:2.2.1 (compile),
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:2.2.1 (compile),
>   org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.3.1.4 (test),
>   org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.2 (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.2 (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.2 (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.5.2 (compile),
>   log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 (runtime),
>   commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 (runtime),
>   com.tata:middleware:jar:5.0.0 (compile), com.tata:PRO:jar:1.0.0
>   (compile), com.tata:legacy.backoffice:jar:1.0.0 (compile),
>   hessian:hessian:jar:3.0.8 (compile),
>   commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1 (runtime),
>   xstream:xstream:jar:1.2.2 (compile), bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:140
>   (runtime), org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.8 (compile),
>   net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.1 (runtime)]: Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:99.1:
>   Could not transfer artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:pom:99.1
>   from/to maven-central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven/): No connector
>   available to access repository maven-central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven/) of type legacy using the available
>   factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory,
>   WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]

---

**// Before**

```
 <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>codehaus</id>
                <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>Apache Incubating Repository</id>
                <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating-repository</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>apache-snapshot</id>
                <name>Apache Maven Snapshot</name>
                <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
```

**after**

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://nexus.sonatype.org/url>  <!--Here i did a change-->
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Apache Incubating Repository</id>
            <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating-repository</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-snapshot</id>
            <name>Apache Maven Snapshot</name>
            <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to access Maven 1 legacy repositories.

Please check this answer:

[How to use a maven 1 repository with maven 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006391/how-to-use-a-maven-1-repository-with-maven-2)

"The [Nexus repository manager](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) is able to proxy Maven 1 repositories for Maven {2,3} clients."

Comment: Thank you very much , i have checked that link before , and i replaced the repository tag with this  http://nexus.sonatype.org/ and tried to build , but still the error exists ,please help .

Comment: Is changing the repository tag is sufficient or do we need to do some settings also ??

Comment: can you post your pom.xml or at least the relevant part, maybe before and after your change.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the "<" in your end URL tag

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://nexus.sonatype.org</url>  <!--Here is your problem-->
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>codehaus</id>
        <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Apache Incubating Repository</id>
        <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating-repository</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>apache-snapshot</id>
        <name>Apache Maven Snapshot</name>
        <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
```